# Keyboard arrows move windows between screens in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

A few days ago I updated Windows 7 to Windows 10, but now the keyboard arrows have a strange behavior. The PC has 2 screens and when I press the keyborard arrows (up, down, left and right) the active window change between screens or minimize or maximize.

For example if the active window is in the right screen if I press left arrow the window change to the left screen, if I press up arrow the active window is maximized and if I press down the active window is minimized.

I only press keyboard arrows, I don't press any modificator key (such as control or alt).

This problem did not happen in windows 7.

How can I disable this behavior?

Thanks

Edit: I tried other keyboard and happen the same.

Comment: Sounds like your Windows key is stuck

Comment: I forget to say that I tried with other keyboard and the same problem happen. I have edited the question to clear that point. Thanks

Comment: Do the other keys work correctly? What happens if you press win button + arrows?

Comment: The other keys work correctly. If I press win key + arrow key the active window change between left, center and right of screen 1 and left, center and right of screen 2. If I press win key + shift key + arrow key it has a similar behavior that if I press only the arrows key (The only difference is that if the active windows is in the right screen and I press right arrow key the active windows doesn't move but if I press win key + shift key + right arrow key the active windows move to the left screen)

Comment: What did it end up being?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens if Windows key is pressed.

I'd faced this issue and I tried pressing Windows key once again and things were back to normal.

Comment: In Windows (or maybe: in the electronics of the hardware) modifier keys sometimes get stuck, and when I can't log in, or clicks do unexpected things, I hit the following keys once, each: Left-Shift, Left-Ctrl, Left-Win, Left-Alt, and their right counterparts. And Caps Lock two or three times, whatever number makes the Caps Lock indicator be off when I'm done.

Answer (score -3):

Try ALT + Windows Key ... it worked for me. Hope it does for you.